# Find which vec3 rotation to apply to align 2 triangles

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, rotation, trigonometry

I have a situation, I have 2 bodies and let's suppose one of them is in T-Pose and the other is idle, with it's arms looking down.
I have to find which rotation was applied to your elbow, for example, to match first body's (elbow-to-hand bone) with second body's (elbow-to-hand bone).
I thought about taking three vertex's (they have almost the same meshes, so that's not a problem but I cannot use vertex's normals bcause they're not the same).

Then the thing is, I have three points forming a triangle on first body and 3 points forming another triangle on second body and I want to find which rotation needs to be applied to one of the triangles to match the other.

If it helps, I'm doing it with unity and c#.

EDIT: IMPORTANT! triangles might not have the same dimensions but they are 2d so I only need to know it's rotation

Comment: So you need to know what rotation should be applied to bone (parent of triangle) rather than "rotation of triangle", right?

Comment: Why not use the transforms of the bones rather than the vertex approach?

Comment: I'm copying bones from one body to another, the thing is one body is in t pose and the other might be with arms looking down so there's a problem because for example, wrist bone isn't on it's correct position on the new body, that's why I use vertex's to know where this bone should be. The problem is I can set the correct bone's position but I cannot do the same for the rotation @mlkn

Comment: @Absinthe upper comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to find the transformation between two configurations of the same triangle in 2D: {v1,v2,v3} and {w1, w2,w3}. I assume you know vertex correspondance, for example v1->w1, v2->w2, v3->w3.

Here is what you can do:
 1. find rotation angle between the two configurations. 
 2. rotate a point, for example v1 and obtain rotatedV1
 3. find translation between rotatedV1 and w1.

Here is the code. For the sake of simplicity, I used WPF struct Vector3D. The final result is a standard double array collecting a 4x4 transformation matrix

```
    static void miniTest() {

        // first triangle 
        Vector3D v1 = new Vector3D();
        Vector3D v2 = new Vector3D(2, 0, 0);
        Vector3D v3 = new Vector3D(2, 3, 0);

        Vector3D w1 = new Vector3D(0,-1, 0);
        Vector3D w2 = new Vector3D(0 , -3, 0);
        Vector3D w3 = new Vector3D(3, -1, 0);


        double[,] transofrmation = getTrMatrix(v1, v2, v3, w1, w2, w3);    

    }

    public static double[,] getTrMatrix(Vector3D V1, Vector3D V2, Vector3D V3, Vector3D W1, Vector3D W2, Vector3D W3) {
        Vector3D s1 = V2 - V1;
        s1.Normalize();

        Vector3D z1 = W2 - W1;
        z1.Normalize();

        double angle = Math.Acos(Vector3D.DotProduct(s1, z1));

        double[,] rotT = new double[,] {
            { Math.Cos(angle), -Math.Sin(angle), 0},
            { Math.Sin(angle), Math.Cos(angle), 0},
            { 0,0,1},
        };

        double[] rotatedV1 = multiply(rotT, V1);

        Vector3D translation = new Vector3D( W1.X - rotatedV1[0], W1.Y - rotatedV1[1], W1.Z - rotatedV1[2]);

        double[,] T = new double[,] {
            { Math.Cos(angle), -Math.Sin(angle), 0, translation.X},
            { Math.Sin(angle), Math.Cos(angle), 0, translation.Y},
            { 0,0,1, translation.Z},
            {0,0,0,1 } };

        return T;
    }


    // apply rotation matrix to vector
    static double[] multiply(double[,] rotMat, Vector3D vec) {

        double[] result = new double[3];

        result[0] = rotMat[0, 0] * vec.X + rotMat[0, 1] * vec.Y + rotMat[0, 2] * vec.Z;
        result[1] = rotMat[1, 0] * vec.X + rotMat[1, 1] * vec.Y + rotMat[1, 2] * vec.Z;
        result[1] = rotMat[2, 0] * vec.X + rotMat[2, 1] * vec.Y + rotMat[2, 2] * vec.Z;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'll take a look and tell you what